# How to do a documentation page like sencha's?

Tags: extjs

In the sencha documentation page, when I click a class, a class tap appears, and there will be a toobar up there usually features two buttons (are they buttons) "properties" and "methods". When the mouse is on these two buttons, a overall properties/methods list will appear.

It seems that list is dynamically generated. Can anyone please help. I'd like to do a similar page on my site, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sencha uses JSDuck (https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck) to generate the documentation. There are instructions in the repo regarding how to add your own classes to it, and it's pretty easy to do. Additionally, you should be able to see the source for how they are handling the menus/dropdowns.